# Circuit analysis of a vacuum tube diode

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, kirchhoffs-laws

To understand modern semiconductor diodes, I looked up their simpler predecessors to get to know what is actually expected of them when I saw this circuit.

How can I do an electrical analysis of this circuit (Kvl or Kcl)?

[image: Image taken from the book RCA Receiving Tube Manual]

Image taken from the book RCA Receiving Tube Manual (http://www.tubebooks.org/tubedata/rc30.pdf) Page 7

Comment: There's a great tube-primer on this link:  http://www.valvewizard.co.uk/gainstage.html    A read through of that and you'll see the similarities of tube & transistor design.  They're alot like N-channel MOSFETs actually.

Comment: @KyleB I'd say triodes are more like JFETs than MOSFETs, due to the way you'd get current into the grid if you bias it positive relative to the cathode.

Comment: @hearth  You're thinking of enhancement mode MOSFET.   My bad --- I should have been clearer --- It's an analog of a depletion mode MOSFET.    http://www.geofex.com/Article_Folders/mosfet_folly/mosfetfolly.htm      They're darn close to a 'drop in replacement' even

Comment: Treat the diode as if it was a resistor connected to the negative filament terminal.

Comment: @KyleB Even in a depletion mode MOSFET, you don't get current through the gate in steady-state, regardless of bias. In a JFET you do, and in a vacuum triode you also do. That's why I say they're more comparable to JFETs.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what there is to analyze.

There's some current flow from plate to cathode (electrons are emitted from the heated filament/cathode), so the voltage across the output resistor, vacuum tube and ammeter add up to the B battery voltage, plus or minus (depending on which you pick as the cathode) some portion (maybe half) of the (much lower) filament voltage. It's more complex than it needs to be because of the directly heated cathode.

In practice often the cathode would be indirectly heated by an electrically isolated filament...

[image]

or the DC output would be taken from the center-tap of the transformer winding driving a directly heated cathode.

[image]

The vacuum tube has similar characteristics to a semiconductor diode, albeit with considerably higher resistance when forward biased, and less offset:

[image]
(one word on the diagram is in error, it should say "space charge limited").

Diagrams from [Vacuum Tube Rectifiers](http://www.tubebooks.org/books/schure_rectifiers.pdf) Alexander Schure.

You will find a similar characteristic curve in the RCA Receiving tube manual, where you likely plucked the image you used (please give credit for images on SE).

Comment: Sorry, it's my first time here, I've edited it. I also wanted to ask you if there is a book with in depth analysis of vacuum tubes (where i actually see formulas like in MOSFETS). I have no clue about vacuum tubes, hence I'm looking for a book. Another question is, what did you mean by less offset? (is it in reference to threshold voltage?)

Comment: The amount of voltage required to get a reasonable amount of current flowing. But I'm not sure that statement is correct, zero current voltage seems to be something like 500mV for some vacuum tube diodes. Aside from the RCA etc. manuals, the MIT Rad Lab series .